# In Visual Studio 2013, how do I work on a local database and then deploy only the changes to Azure?

Tags: database, azure, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I am doing development in VS 2013 against local instances of SQL Server - both an actual SQL Server instance and also a localDB.  Is there a way I can deploy changes (schema and data) I make locally to an Azure instance of that database?

Comment: there are a few different ways to accomplish this, depending on how you are actually managing your data.  For example, are you using Entity Framework? We need a bit more information to guide you here.

Comment: @AndrewCounts - I will be using either ADO.NET or LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

For a more comprehensive control over Development, Deployment (full & partial [changes only]), and Migration of SQL Databases to SQL Azure you might need a separate tool called SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) Full list of features and help available here : msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj156163.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I looked at these articles and they appear to relate to deploying an entire database.  Is there a way I can generate change-scripts, eg scripts that deploy only the changes?

Comment: For a more comprehensive control over Development, Deployment and Migration of SQL Databases to SQL Azure you might need a separate tool called SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) Full list of features and help available here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj156163.aspx

Comment: The "How to: Use SQL Server Data Tools to Migrate a Database to Azure SQL Database" article you linked to hits the nail on the head because the process it describes allows for the deployment of *changes* to schema as opposed to whole database migrations.  If you edit your answer to reflect this article and focus on the change aspect of things (rather than whole db migrations) I will mark it as accepted.